# Impersonation/False portrayal of character - maximum punishment?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

There are 2 individuals, Person A and Person B.

Let's say that `A` is hellbent on ruining `B's` life, but not in the way some/most people would think.

`A` has stolen pretty much all of `B's` personal information, (SS#, emails, texts, etc)

`A` also wants to make sure no one suspects him to be involved in the slightest.

How does he do this?

As a promoter/marketer, he knows that if he were to promote something in `B's` name, no one would ever think that someone else is doing it.

Instead, `A` fabricates content making it appear to come from `B` and purposefully spreads it around under the lie that `B` does not like to talk about his personal life and other lies to make it seem legitimate.

Basically, he is pretending to be `B` and is narrating his life and promoting things as if it were coming from him.

Let's say that he's created this whole false persona that he's gotten even `B's` family and friends to believe it.

An example would be spreading false content about `B's` friend and causing them to believe there are issues between them, when none existed in the first place.

**QUESTION**

Let's say all of this is true. `B` is living his life having knowing that he has never done anything to promote himself in any way, he has never written, spoken, etc about his life or his family/friends in any way.

But because of `A`, no one believes `B` and as a result, no one will help him because they think he is lying.

What kind of recourse or maximum punishment can be dealt to the perpetrator, if and when any/all evidence if found?

Let's say this is in the USA.

Comment: This would be in the USA, not sure if state by state matters